# Show that the iterations $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$ converges to $b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:[a,b]→[a,b]$ be a differentiable and strictly increasing function where $b$ is the unique fixed point of $f$ and $f([a,b])⊂[a,b]$.

Show that the iterations $$x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$$ converges to $b$. I have no idea to start.

Comment: "$f$ strictly increasing" means 
$
x_{n} < x_{n+1}
$
 for all $n$.  So, your sequence is also strictly increasing and bounded above by $b$.  Show that no smaller upper bound exists.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant in your comment about the converse.

Comment: @avs: this is an error sorry.

Comment: In that case, my first comment stands.:)  BTW, I don't see why you need differentiability.

Comment: @avs: Yes. But I am not able to prove that.

Comment: Go by contradiction: suppose a point $b_{1}$ in $(a, b)$ is an upper bound for the sequence.  Then $b _{1} < f(b_{1}) < b$.  Now if a point $x_{n}$ in the sequence is close enough to $b_{1}$ (and there are such points by the construction of $b_{1}$), then $f(x_{n}) > b_{1}$.

Comment: @avs: Yes, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the sequence  $a_n=f^n(a)$ and show that it is strictly increasing. Show that its limit has to be $b$ and thus the fixed point. Then for any point $x_0\in [a,b]$ you get $a_n\le x_n\le b$.